# IE 8 bug? Drop shadow with Gradient background, and the text becomes grey

Tags: css, internet-explorer

This is an example on http://jsfiddle.net/Eu5by/11/  and on http://jsfiddle.net/Eu5by/12/

(**Update:** actually, it doesn't need to be a link: see http://jsfiddle.net/Eu5by/14/ and it is just text)

the code is basically:

```
<div id="main-box">    
  <a id="box" href="http://www.google.com">
      hello world
  </a>    
</div>
```

with the CSS

```
#main-box {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#dddddd')
}

#box {
    display: block; width: 300px; height: 60px; line-height: 60px; text-align: center; background: #ffc; color: #ff7000;

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f3f9ff', endColorstr='#e8f3ff',GradientType=0 )
}
```

the text will appear gray on IE 8.   The first jsfiddle link uses `filter` while the second one uses `-ms-filter`  Is there a way to fix this?

(I am trying on IE 8 on a virtual machine.  If it is on my IE 9 then it works fine.)

**On IE 8, if either the drop shadow or the gradient is removed, then the link will have the correct color again.**

Comment: Wrapping the text in another inner element width `color:red !important` seems to have no effect either...

Comment: @Charliepiga: Drop IE is not a solution for people who do this for a living.

Comment: @Madmartigan, that's why i put that in a comment and not in an answer :)

Comment: @Charliepiga: "drop IE6" I would agree with wholeheartedly. Even "drop IE7" would get my support if it didn't do what you need. Dropping IE8 is a crazy suggestion - it may not be up to standard, but it is still being supplied as the default browser on virtually all new machines sold today. Maybe in four or five years time it'll have lost enough market share to consider dropping it, but I reckon it'll be considerably longer than that.

Comment: On the other hand, I would counsel against using IE's filters unless it's absolutely necessary. The effects may be nice, but the hassle they cause means they're generally not worth it, unless you're using them via a wrapper like CSS3Pie, which attempts to make IE conform to some CSS3 standards, and makes it slightly more tolerable to work with some of these effects.

Comment: @Spudley: Why does using CSS3Pie make a difference, they simply convert css to use the `filter` property anyways, and there are still lots of bugs with it. I will say this: `pie.htc` changed my life :) Couldn't do without it!

Comment: @Madmartigan - for a start, Pie makes the syntax much easier. For a second, Pie makes it easier to combine the filtered styles (IE has some major issues around this, which Pie deals with silently behind the scenes).

Comment: @Spudley: Easier syntax does not matter when it comes to bugs, but I did not realize that Pie did anything to help reduce bugs by intelligently combining filters, thanks for that info. I personally have never needed or wanted to use filters, same reason I don't use -webkit or -moz properties: It has to all look the same (unfortunately). Clients get confused and angry when they see something that looks one way on their work computer and another way on their ipad at home. I'm hoping that IE9 adoption will make 8 obsolete sooner than later but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: @Spudley @Madmartigan Do you think CSS3Pie can have these 2 effects (shadow and gradient) and make the bug go away?  Maybe CSS3Pie has some hacks or workaround so that some bugs do not show up?

Comment: Yes, I'd suggest giving CSS3Pie a go; it does support gradients and box shadows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [bug documented on QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2007/08/alphaimageloader_filter_shows_backgrounds_on_zoom_.html).

Try setting the zoom factor to anything other than 100% ;)